# How to implement this ArcGIS please give me guidance.. Thanks in advance

Tags: visualforce

this is JavaScript served from the https://js.arcgis.com that allows mapping applications to be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/ this is JavaScript served from the https://js.arcgis.com that allows mapping applications to be provided.

To use the code in Salesforce you can just paste all the HTML into a Visualforce page. A Visualforce page has to have the apex:page tag at its root:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false"
        standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
    <html>
        ...
    </html>
</apex:page>
```

It would only be worth creating an App Exchange Application if you provided a significant amount of added value in what you did with the ArcGIS code. You would also need to take care to stay within the terms of use of the software.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith C. Also tell me How to Add ArcGIS Direction Widget feature to the AppExchange Application???

Comment: Hi Keith C.. when creating Visualforce apge getting below error.. Please help me. Error: DirectionWidget line 60, column 5: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>" 
Error Error: The element type "link" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</link>".

Comment: @praveen Sorry but I don't know anything about that widget. Visualforce requires the tags to be [well formed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_element) i.e. every open tag has to have a close tag so you need `<link ...></link>` or `<link ... />`.

Comment: The terms of use of every single piece of mapping software out there is laid out as private/corporate use costs lots and lots of money. The lone exception is OpenStreetMap if and only if you set up and host your own tile server.